# Keeping a Reveal modal open on form error

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have a link that fires a Reveal modal:

```
<a data-reveal-id="myModal" href="#">Open</a>
```

The Reveal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
<h2>Join us in the celebration!</h2>
<p><em>Required fields are marked with a: <strong>*</strong></em></p>
{form}
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

If the form is submitted with errors, the error messages display next to the form fields, but the Reveal modal closes. The user most-likely thinks everything is cool, but really nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this jQuery to look for the error class in the form and fire the modal again (with errors displayed):

```
var $findError = $('div.form').find ('div');
    if ( $findError.hasClass('form_error')){
    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
}
```